# Eigenvalues of $A^T A$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a real, positive-definite, symmetric matrix $M$, calculated from a matrix $A$ which is known:

$M = A^\top A$

Given the nature of $M$, is there any specialised (read: fast code and/or simple code) way to find the largest eigenvalue of $M$?  It's years since I did linear algebra, so I'm a bit rusty.  I've had a look in Numerical Recipes, Wikipedia and the Matrix cookbook.

I found the following in the Matrix cookbook and got excited too early:

> > For a symmetric, positive-definite matrix $A$:
> >
> > $eig\left(A A^\top\right) = eig\left(A^\top A\right) = eig\left(A\right) \cdot eig\left(A\right)$

Of course, it is $M$ that is positive-definite and symmetric, not $A$.  $A$ isn't even square.  M will probably be 1024x1024 or larger.  The size of $M$ (i.e. width of $A$) can be constrained by the algorithm if needed, i.e. I don't mind if your suggestions require that it be a multiple of 4 or a power of 2.

[Edit:]
I'm mainly looking for something that I can code natively (taking advantage of SSE/AVX where possible), although your MATLAB/Octave suggestions will definitely be useful to aid my understanding of the algorithms!

Comment: [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of $A$ might help. I don't know however if there are specialized algorithms which calculate only the largest singular values.

Comment: [scicomp.stackexchange.com](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: I expect any mathematical software package will have specialized routines for this, as it is a quite common requirement. For example, in Mathematica, `Eigenvalues[Transpose[A].A, 1]` or `SingularValueList[A, 1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple iterative algorithm to find the largest eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix $B$ is to compute repeatedly $x_{n+1} = B \, x_n$ starting from a random vector $x_0$, normalizing the length in each iteration. When it converges, you've found an eigenvector, and then you get the eigenvalue. There are some complications (repeated eigenvalues, event that $x_0$ is very near another eigenvector, etc), but that's the idea. Eg in Octave:

```
>>> A = rand(A,4); B = A'*A;  x = rand(1,4);
>>> x = x * B  /norm(x)
x =   1.7215   2.4537   2.3203   1.5036
>>> x = x * B  /norm(x)
x =   1.9544   3.0235   2.8072   1.6825
>>> x = x * B  /norm(x)
x =   1.9484   3.0362   2.8112   1.6717
>>> x = x * B  /norm(x)
x =   1.9477   3.0372   2.8113   1.6705
>>> x = x * B  /norm(x)
x =   1.9476   3.0373   2.8113   1.6704
>>> x = x * B  /norm(x)
x =   1.9476   3.0373   2.8113   1.6704
>>> norm(x * B) / norm(x)
ans =  4.8695
>>> eig(B)
ans =  0.074894   0.130166   0.485889   4.869534
```

Comment: Recalling the classroom of eigenvalues+vectors as measurements of stretching and the corresponding directions, your method makes loads of sense (in addition to a nice simplicity about it).  It will also play nicely with SSE or GPU optimisation, I'll profile it against Ed Gorcenski's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

There are algorithms to compute the largest eigenvalues; in fact, many eigenvalue algorithms compute the eigenvalues in descending order (according to magnitude).

However, to compute just the single largest eigenvalue, the algorithm in [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.178.4733&rep=rep1&type=pdf) should work, but it is too complex to describe completely here.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at Lanczos on wikipedia before I decided to ask on here - I'll give that paper a proper read tomorrow!